# Required Parameters for testing IdentityServer Token endpoint using PostMan

Tags: jwt, postman, identityserver4

What are the required parameters for configuring a Identity Server Client to test it using PostMan?
Also, whet are the parameters needed to be sent to identity server Token Endpoint (/connect/token) from PostMan.
All these using Identity server 4 with asp.net core identity.

Comment: could you past some code, for instance how do you configure IdentityServer in Startup.cs? which clients do you have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can follow this quickstart to set up the server. [*Identity Server Quickstart*](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/0_overview.html)

The parameters you need to send to the server token endpoint are:

- client_id
- client_secret
- grant_type
- scope

There may be some additional parameters needed but this depends on your grant type. For a grant type of client credentials those params will be enough. You can find more info here [Identity Server Token Endpoint](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/endpoints/token.html)